# Grinder agent fails to report data to console through ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-tunnel, grinder

I'm using Vagrant ssh to connect to a remote Grinder agent while running the console locally:

vagrant ssh agent01 -c "./startAgent.sh" -- -R 6372:localhost:6372

The console can talk to the agent, and start the agent's threads:

```
2015-07-24 10:12:54,391 INFO  agent: The Grinder 3.11
2015-07-24 10:12:54,507 INFO  agent: connected to console at /127.0.0.1:6372
2015-07-24 10:12:54,507 INFO  agent: waiting for console signal
2015-07-24 10:12:57,869 INFO  agent: received a start message
2015-07-24 10:12:57,887 INFO  agent: Worker process command line: java '-javaagent:grinder-3.11/lib/grinder-dcr-agent-3.11.jar' -classpath 'grinder-3.11/lib/grinder.jar' net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint
2015-07-24 10:12:57,967 INFO  agent: worker agent01-0 started
2015-07-24 10:12:57,976 INFO  agent: worker agent01-1 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,007 INFO  agent: worker agent01-2 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,032 INFO  agent: worker agent01-3 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,059 INFO  agent: worker agent01-4 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,095 INFO  agent: worker agent01-5 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,156 INFO  agent: worker agent01-6 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,182 INFO  agent: worker agent01-7 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,214 INFO  agent: worker agent01-8 started
2015-07-24 10:12:58,250 INFO  agent: worker agent01-9 started
```

Shortly thereafter, though, the agents say:

```
2015-07-24 10:13:38,016 INFO  agent01-2: Report to console failed
net.grinder.communication.CommunicationException: Exception whilst sending message
  at net.grinder.communication.AbstractSender.send(AbstractSender.java:57) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.communication.QueuedSenderDecorator.flush(QueuedSenderDecorator.java:60) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess.sendStatusMessage(GrinderProcess.java:638) [grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess.access$1100(GrinderProcess.java:110) [grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess$ReportToConsoleTimerTask.run(GrinderProcess.java:615) ~[grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess.run(GrinderProcess.java:465) [grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.run(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:86) [grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
  at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.main(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:59) [grinder-core-3.11.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]

...
```

and never provide data to the console.

What causes this? Is there ssh configuration I need to tweak?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I added this line to /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the grinder agent host:

```
MaxStartups 1000
```

and changed the grinder agent properties from:

```
grinder.processes = 10
grinder.threads = 100
```

to

```
grinder.processes = 4
grinder.threads = 250
```